# D3 scale based on window size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 **v3** and was going through some tutorial on basic linear and ordinal scales. I am modifying a piece of code from the tutorial. I want to make the colors do be displayed and scaled according to the size of the window. If there are more data then it should again space evenly to fit all the data.

```js
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

var padding = 2, dataLength = data.length;

var Xscale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([data.min, data.max])
    .range([0,window.innerWidth]); 

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
        "width" : window.innerWidth,
        "height" : window.innerHeight
    });

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");

rects.attr({
    "fill": function(d) {return colorScale(d);},
    "x" : function(d , i) {return Xscale(d);},
    "width" : window.innerWidth / dataLength - padding,
    "height" : 50
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone help me with the above mentioned code and provide few guidelines on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can I make a constructive criticism? `Xscale` is a strange name in JavaScript, it'd be normally `xScale`. In JS, we normally start with lowercase, and put a Uppercase for another "word". For instance `someValue`, `interestingExample`, `certainFunction` etc... Of course, you can name them anyway you want!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and telling me the conventional way to declare variables in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` and `min` are not properties of `data`, which is simply a flat array. Thus, there is no `data.max` or `data.min`, and your `Xscale` domain right now is this:

```
[Nan, Nan]
```

Of course, you're not getting anywhere with NaNs.

Instead of that, you're looking for:

```
.domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
var data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();

var padding = 2,
  dataLength = data.length;

var Xscale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
  .range([0, window.innerWidth]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": window.innerWidth,
    "height": window.innerHeight
  });

var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

rects.attr({
  "fill": function(d) {
    return colorScale(d);
  },
  "x": function(d, i) {
    return Xscale(d);
  },
  "width": window.innerWidth / dataLength - padding,
  "height": 50
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```